# how to check for specific characters inside csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm have read a CSV file into pandas dataframe and trying to find all the sentences that contains the words I'm looking for and when ever finding any of them print it with its original index from the main CSV not a new index. this is the code I'm trying but it gives me an error for some reason

```
lookfor = '[' + re.escape(",?!.:;'؛؛؟'-)(؛،؛«/") + ']'


tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(tdata.count(' ') == 0)
tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

newdata=tdata[tdata['sentences'].str.isin(lookfor)]

print (newdata)


#a sample set
-----------------------------

#hi, how are; you 
#im good thanks
#How ? Is live.
#good, what about ) you/
#my name is alex
#hello, alex how are you !
#im good!
#great news
#thanks!
-----------------------------
```

it returns this error

```
newdata=tdata[tdata['sentences'].str.isin(pat)]
AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

input data looks like

[image]

output I'm expecting is

[image]

Comment: Do provide some data, with expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy i added some mate

Comment: Characters inside regex character classes generally do not need to be `re.escape()`d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the 'contains' method, something like

```py
df = tdata[tdata.sentences.str.contains(pat, regex=True, na=False)]
```

Full code should look something like;

```py
lookfor = '[' + re.escape(",?!.:;'؛؛؟'-)(؛،؛«/") + ']'

tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(tdata.count(' ') == 0)
tdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

tdata['row_index'] = 1
tdata['row_index'] = tdata['row_index'].cumsum()

filtered = tdata[tdata.sentences.str.contains(lookfor, regex=True, na=False)]
filtered.to_csv('./my_path.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: contains() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_values'

Comment: @programming freak Should be ```na``` not ```na_values``` - thanks for the spot - it's just to make sure that NaN values return False.

Comment: that works fine but can I do like the index that is prints +1 ? is that doable within that line so if the index is 7 it will say 8 and so on

Comment: If you have an 'index' column in your data you can do ```df['index'] = df['index']+1```, or if you don't, you could just have something like ```df['index'] = 1``` and then ```df['index'] = df['index'].cumsum()``` to get an increasing index from 1. Would suggest avoiding the column name 'index' as it is used internally in pandas.

Comment: well I dont have any indexes in the main but pandas are creating automatically so what shall I do in this case ??